# Unity3D/PowerUI doesn't register simple CSS translation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity3D wth the PowerUI asset and when I try to make a simple div with a transform:translate(100px, 100px) attribute in CSS, the :hover :active and click events only register from the original positon, check it (and try testing it in unity with powerui):

```js
function test(el) {
 el.innerHTML = "t";
}
```

```css
div#thisDiv{
  position:absolute;
  color:black;
  transform:translate(200px, 100px);
}
div#thisDiv:hover{
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="thisDiv" onclick="test(this)">Bla bla bla</div>
```

It works fine in the browser obviously, but try putting it in a simple Unity3D scene with PowerUI and you'll see it only registers the original position, not the translated one.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Maybe something editable in the Source?